# Best practices for versioning applications with Git, build tools, and CI/CD tools

Tags: java, node.js, git, jenkins, versioning

Say you have applications in popular languages (e.g. Java, Nodejs), with build tools (build.gradle, pom.xml, package.json) and CI/CD tools (e.g. Jenkins, GitLab).

It's common for the CI/CD tools to append a build number at the end of the actual application version specified in the build tool config, e.g. my app's build.gradle / package.json specifies version 1.0.0 and the artefacts produced will have 1.0.0.1 as the version with 1.0.0 being the version in build.gradle / package.json and 1 being the build number of Jenkins.

I like the above approach as it has enough details for traceability.  What I'm not sure about is the steps to do next after a production drop of 1.0.0.1 and for targeting the next version 1.0.1.

1. When do you update the version in build.gradle / package.json to the next target version?  Is it straight after the production release?  Do you automate this with a Jenkins job or do it manually with hand by running a tool and then, pushing to Git?
2. Is the above a common approach?

I'm probably jumbling things, but I'm basically after the standard lifecycle workflow of application versions, given the tools such as build tools, CI/CD tools and version controls.

Comment: if you released `1.0.0`, your next target release is not `1.0.1`. That is a version that means a fix in `1.0.0`, like a hot-fix. We say that the next target one is `1.1.0` or `2.0.0`. In general we say that `x.y.z` : `z` is a hot fix, `y` is the next iteration and `x` is a set of entirely new features. We do it by hand, with bump scripts. For maven, for example: `mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=2.0.3`...

Comment: there are two things you want to read on this : git-workflow and sem versioning.

Comment: Your post is somehow related to semantic versioning : https://semver.org/

Comment: @Eugene Those are applicable to software that "ships", but may not be the best approach to software that's deployed internally.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to versioning application is using number X.Y.Z

***X.Y.Z*** (eg. 1.1.1) - small changes (eg. hot-fixes, small features)
***X.Y.0*** (eg. 1.2.0) - new big features
***X.0.0*** (eg. 2.0.0) - big changes (eg. changes app logic, new frameworks..)

Additionally good practice is using versions release candidate to running in non production environment eg. for tests eg. ***1.1.1rc1, 2.0.0rc1***

Process release app is starting from develop branch, there is bump version to eg. **1.0.0** in pom.xml and then merge to master branch. Jenkins after webhook on master branch build docker image with version from pom.xml and push app docker image to docker repository.